# Gauss-Legendre weights convertion from [-1,1] to [a,b]

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Ok so we know for integration with the Gauss-Legendre method :
$\int_1^1f(x)dx = \sum_{i=0}^nc_i^nf(x_i)$

that both $x_i,c_i$ are fixed,depending on $n$ , when we work at the [-1,1] space. I know that for converting $x_i$ from [-1,1]->[a,b] I have to do the following:

$y_i=\frac{(b+a)}{2}+ \frac{(b-a)}{2}x_i$

But what about the weights for the G-L. How do I convert the $c_i$ weights from [-1,1] to [a,b]???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a function $g \colon [a, b] \to \mathbb{R},$ define the transformed function:
$$
f \colon [-1, 1] \to \mathbb{R}, \ x \mapsto g\left(\frac{b+a}2 + \frac{b-a}2x\right).
$$
The standard formula you have quoted, when applied to $f,$ gives:
\begin{align*}
\int_a^b g(y)\,dy & = \frac{b-a}2\int_{-1}^1f(x)\,dx \\
& \bumpeq \frac{b-a}2\sum_{i=0}^nc_i^nf(x_i) \\
& = \frac{b-a}2\sum_{i=0}^nc_i^ng(y_i),
\end{align*}
so the effect is that the weights $c_i^n$ are multiplied by $\frac{b-a}2.$

Comment: Mercifully, Wikipedia agrees: [Gaussian quadrature - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_quadrature#Change_of_interval) ("Change of interval").